# What is working better: Word to Latex or PDF to Latex?

Tags: word-to-latex

I have written an article with co-authors that do not use LaTeX - however it needs to go in my dissertation, that's why I need to make it into LaTeX. Is there any comparison on what works better: Word to LaTeX or PDF to LaTeX?

I know I will have a lot of work on my hands, either way.

Comment: if you don't need to change the layout or refer to items in it, why not just include it as a pdf?

Comment: Take PDF and include "as is". Or take the Word file, copy & paste the text and redo the markup by hand.

Comment: @daleif my thesis will look wild if I just include all the articles in the different journals' styles  :( Said anachronism that cumulative thesis should look like a book.

Comment: In that case, why not give the various doc2tex or rtf2tex converters a try? There is certainly more semantic information in a Word document to work with than in plain PDF.

Comment: Thank you Ingmar - really didn’t know what’s the best converter :)

Comment: depends on how the word file has been made, but if they used proper mark up for section etc, then pandoc is worth a try.

Comment: I think my main problem are the references and those probably won’t work, right?

Comment: Are you using any kind of reference management tool? If so it shouldn't be too difficult to convert the references used to a Latex-readable format. (I would anyway recommend using them, makes life much easier.)

Comment: Yes it’s done with Mendeley!

Comment: I have judged many theses over the years for both UK and US universities. If they included a copy of an article published elsewhere I would accept that in its original format but if the format was changed I would reject it because it would not be identical to the original (and who is to judge how accurate the transformation is?). --- GOM

Comment: Thanks Peter Wilson, I would have loved to do that. However all the other PhD students with my supervisor and institution had to do it that way (I.e. make it text not picture) :(